# SQL - Select rows based on column value and

Tags: sql, group-by, max, rank

I have a table like this:

```
CustomerID - ProductID - Score

Customer1  -  Product1 -- 9
Customer1  -  Product2 -- 10
Customer2  -  Product3 -- 11
Customer2  -  Product4 -- 7
Customer3  -  Product1 -- 6
```

I want to group it by customerID. and pick only that row for a customer which has highest score
SO, my table should become:

```
Customer1  -  Product2 -- 10
Customer2  -  Product3 -- 11
Customer3  -  Product1 -- 6
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Do some Googling on GROUP BY and HAVING MAX. You'll be better for figuring it out than someone handing you a solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) `rank` function to order the rows in subgroup and select first rank rows, Something like below.

```
Select * from 
(
    Select CustomerId, 
    productId, 
    Score,
    Rank() Over (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY Score DESC) AS Rnk
) query Where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
SELECT CUST_ID,PROD_ID, MAX(SCORE) AS SCORE FROM TABLE GROUP BY CUST_ID,PROD_ID;

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a 'group by' into a temp table including the max value, and then inner join to your temp table.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

http://codingsight.com/introduction-to-temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

You can't do what you're trying to in a single select statement, because SQL Server can't actually tell what the max value is until the first select statement has finished running. That's why you need to write a second query and do your join based on the row having the same value as the temp table